# Error no such file or directory en servidor con Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, servidor

Tengo un proyecto realizado con el framework **Codeigniter** el cual al momento de subirlo al servidor e intentar descargar un archivo *Excel* con la ayuda de la librería *PHPExcel* me esta marcando el siguiente error:

> require_once(application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

En local me funciona de la siguiente manera, en la carpeta *libraries*:

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Ya intente de  las siguientes maneras:

```
Manera 1:
    require_once "../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
    require_once "../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
Manera 2:
    require_once BASEPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
    require_once BASEPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
```

Mas sin embargo me sigue marcando error, al igual ya le di *permisos 777* a todas las carpetas pensando que es error por permisos, pero me marca el mismo error.
La estructura de mis carpetas es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier comentario para poder solucionar mi problemática.

Comment: Al parecer la ruta del PHPExcel.php está mal. Tu aplicación cuando la subes al servidor se llama application? Si pudieras subir una imagen de la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto podría darte una mejor solución.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia ya coloque la imagen de la estructura del proyecto

Comment: puede ser un problema de minúsculas y mayúsculas, en el require dice `PHPExcel` y en la captura dice `PhpExcel`. por otro lado `APPPATH` ya debería venir con el último slash: si te fijas en index.php (v2) `define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');` e index.php (v3) `define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Comment: @aloMalbarez justo es lo que estaba pasando era el nombre de la carpeta la que estaba mal, lo raro que en local si me funcionaba; escribe tu respuesta para darla como valida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser un problema de minúsculas y mayúsculas, en el require dice `PHPExcel` y en la captura dice `PhpExcel`.

La razón de que funcione en local puede ser que estés usando windows, que no reconoce diferencias entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Al probarlo en el servidor (que seguramente no es windows) se respetan las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Por otro lado `APPPATH` ya debería venir con el último slash:

`index.php` (Codeigniter v2.x):

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
```

`index.php` (Codeigniter v3.x):

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Así que

```
require_once APPPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
```

(sin el `/` al principio) debería funcionar ferpecto.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma es utilizar el BASEPATH, por lo que la solución que te doy es utlizar esta ruta:

```
require_once BASEPATH."application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once BASEPATH."application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
```

Suponiendo que en BASEPATH tienes metido la ruta "/public_html/", luego tendrías que ir recorriendo las carpetas hasta entrar a las dos librerías.

En caso de no querer utilizar la ruta completa te faktaría añadir otro "../" tal que así:

```
require_once "../../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once "../../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
```

Ya que tienes con el primero marcas la carpeta libraries, con el segudo marcas la carpeta application y después tienes que entrar en la carpeta "third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php".